# How to return a float number with 2 decimal places without using format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If `n = 19.879287624` then how to change it into `n = 19.87` without using format, which means *n* remains a float and not a string. Obviously, *round* is irrelevant since it returns 19.88 and not 19.87. I checked other similar questions but most of answers were using format and the rest (without using format) were not clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
n = 19.879287624

n = int(n*100)/100
```

It will give you `19.87`.

I think it's pretty obvious, but in case it isn't: multiplying by 100 moves the decimal place to the right by two spaces, forcing it to be an `int` truncates the rest, then dividing that `int` by 100 moves the decimal place back where it belongs.